# Sorting an array from biggest to least in Assembly language x86

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I'm trying to sort an array using the registers from biggest to least and nothing seems to be working. The ecx is my amount of numbers that I have, the esi is the address of my list which consists of dwords. I use the edx to keep going up by 4 bytes to each element. My code doesn't sort the entire array I know that I need to find the location of the max and then set it equal to the outer loops edx but I can't seem to figure out how to change the elements in the array because I only have the edx register. I tried pushing the location and then popping it back out when the inner loop was finished but that didn't seem to work. Please anything is appreciated I have been working on this problem for over 4 hours.

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp,esp
mov     ecx,[ebp+8]
mov     esi,[ebp+12]
mov     edx,-4

outerloop:
add     edx,4
push    edx
push    ecx
mov     ebx,[edx+esi]

innerloop:
add     edx,4
mov     eax,[edx+esi]
cmp     ebx,eax
jl      change
finish:
loop    innerloop
pop     ecx
pop     edx
loop    outerloop
jmp     done


change:
mov     [edx+esi],ebx
mov     [edx+esi-4],eax
sub     edx,4
push    edx
mov     edx,offset change1
call    writestring
pop     edx
jmp     finish

done:
pop     ebp
ret     8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a 'reversed' [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (You can of course use any sorting algorithm you wish, but this is simple for an example). I'm not sure what assembler you're using, but here's a short assembly function that will accomplish a sort of `n` int32_t integers stored in array/list `arr`. (This example was written in NASM)

```
;int *sort(int *arr,int n);
sort:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov edx,[ebp+12]

.loop1:
    mov esi,[ebp+8] ;arr ptr
    mov ecx,[ebp+12] ;n number of ints

.loop2:
    mov eax,[esi] ;compare
    mov ebx,[esi+4]
    cmp eax,ebx
    jg .skip

    mov [esi],ebx ;swap
    mov [esi+4],eax

.skip:
    add esi,4 ;perform loop checks
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx,1
    ja .loop2
    dec edx
    ja .loop1

    mov eax,[ebp+8] ;return arr

    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Please keep in mind this example wasn't really optimized (e.g., it iterates too many times through the whole array). Sometimes (esp. in assembly languages), less is more. Instead of offsetting the pointer by ecx/edx, you can increment the array pointer (or a copy of it), and do comparisons using that directly. This way you don't have to keep track of a counter register AND the pointer at the same time. :)